# keras - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, keras, text-classification

Not sure what am I doing wrong:

I've a dataset (all text) and when I try to fit the Tokenizer it fails.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer as Tok

# The maximum number of words to be used. (most frequent)
MAX_NB_WORDS = 50000
# Max number of words in each complaint.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 250
# This is fixed.
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

labels = training_data['group_name']
features = training_data.drop('group_name', axis='columns')

tokenizer = Tok(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(features.values)
```

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'`

I've cleaned the text as follows:

```
REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))


def clean_text(text):   
    text = text.lower() # lowercase text
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text) # replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text. substitute the matched string in REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE with space.
    text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub('', text) # remove symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text. substitute the matched string in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE with nothing. 
    text = text.replace('x', '')

    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) # remove stopwors from text
    return text

print('clean text')
training_data = training_data.applymap(lambda x: clean_text(x))
```

... so I can't see where the `numpy.ndarray` comes from

**UPDATE:**

I was able to understand the problem and workaround it in an ugly manner:

Consolidate all columns to a single one:

```
labels = df['group_name']
features = df.drop('group_name', axis='columns')
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
tmp['txt'] = features[features.columns[1:]].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1
)
```

now it passes the problematic step:

```
tokenizer = Tok(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(tmp['txt'].values)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(tmp['txt'].values)
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
print('Shape of data tensor:', X.shape)
Y = pd.get_dummies(labels).values
print('Shape of label tensor:', Y.shape)
```

However I still want to keep the original columns and don't keep all data in a single column.

How can I achieve that (i.e. get all values from all columns without iterate on nested numpy arrays)?

Comment: I think `x` here: `training_data.applymap(lambda x: clean_text(x))` is a numpy array and not string.

Comment: @Kaveh are you suggesting my 'cleaning' has no effect?

Comment: No. training_data includes an array of labels, and features. When you use `map(lambda x: clean_text(x))`, it gets each row as `x` and pass to `clean_text(x)`, which `x` is an array. So, in the first line where `text.lower()` you wrote raises an error. Because text is not string, but numpy array.

Comment: @Kaveh makes sense - can you suggest an alternative approach to apply it for all rows without change it to numpy array?

Comment: updated my question since I was able to progress a bit

Comment: Can you show some part of training_data? What happens if clean_text first checks for `isinstance(text, str)` and you printed text and type(text) otherwise ? If cell data type for these columns is `str` you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @Trevis I've updated the question so now I'm facing a new problem